# For-loop inside function couldn't iterate the variables

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, function

I'm willing to compute all values of all of variables combinations. However, the code always produces the same values for all iterations.

```
#chsh
import numpy as np
from bell_state import bell_state
from pauli import pauli

#setup of measurement

N_A = 2  #measurement outcomes
N_B = 2 

#Bell_state used
rho = bell_state(1)

#Alice 

A_1 =pauli('Z')
A_2 =pauli('X')

#Bob

B_1 =(1/np.sqrt(2))*(pauli('Z')+pauli('X'))
B_2 =(1/np.sqrt(2))*(pauli('Z')-pauli('X'))

def AB(a,b):
    if a==1 and b==1:
        aabb = np.kron(A_1,B_1)
    elif a==2 and b==1:
        aabb = np.kron(A_2,B_1)
    elif a==1 and b==2:
        aabb = np.kron(A_1,B_2)
    elif a==2 and b==2:
        aabb = np.kron(A_2,B_2)
    else:
        print('error')
    return aabb

def Obs(a,b):
    for a in range(1,N_A):
        for b in range(1,N_B):
            ob =np.trace(np.dot(AB(a,b),rho))
            return ob

IObs = Obs(1,1) + Obs(1,2) + Obs(2,1) - Obs(2,2)
```

The code showed this results, those not what I want

```
Obs(1,1) : 0.7071067811865475 
 Obs(2,1) : 0.7071067811865475 
 Obs(1,2) : 0.7071067811865475 
 Obs(2,2) : 0.7071067811865475 

IObs : 
 1.414213562373095
```

The results what I expected actually as same as the results that (I computed manually without loops by this below code

```
Ob11= np.trace(np.dot(AB(1,1),rho))
Ob21= np.trace(np.dot(AB(2,1),rho))
Ob12= np.trace(np.dot(AB(1,2),rho))
Ob22= np.trace(np.dot(AB(2,2),rho))
```

results of what I want

```
Obs(1,1)  : 0.7071067811865475 
Obs(2,1)  : 0.7071067811865475 
Obs(1,2)  : 0.7071067811865475 
Obs(2,2)  : -0.7071067811865475 

IObs : 
 2.82842712474619
```

Perhaps somebody could help me find what I've done wrong with my for-loop function.
Thank you!

Comment: No, that's NOT the results you got.  `Obs(1,1)` and `Obs(2,1)` and `Obs(1,2)` all return `None`, because the loops will not run.  This cannot be the code you ran.

Comment: Actually, those the results that I got (the above one). If the loops didn't closed with `return ob` that will be ran as you mentioned, all will return to `NONE`. @TimRoberts

Comment: No, `Obs(1, n)` or `Obs(n, 1)` returns `None` (no matter what `n` is) because `range(1, 1)` is empty so the loops are not executed.

Comment: So, how to execute the loops? should I modify something in my code?  The `n` range should be `1,2`.

Comment: If you want `Obs(1,1)` to run one of each loop, then you need `for a in range(N_A+1):`.

Comment: (That should be `for a in range(1,N_A+1):`.)

Comment: I tried ` for a in range(1,N_A+1):`  but still ran as same as before.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is in Obs function here

```py
def Obs(a,b):
    for a in range(1,N_A):
        for b in range(1,N_B):
            ob =np.trace(np.dot(AB(a,b),rho))
            return ob
```

As you might see, the return statement is placed inside the loop block. This makes your code for calculating ob is never executed more than 1, in other word, it is executed exactly once for whatever `a` and `b` you pass to the function.

Based on my assumption (cause I am not too sure about the logic you wanted to implement), you may want to try to use this instead:

```py
def Obs(a,b):
    for a in range(1,N_A):
        for b in range(1,N_B):
            ob =np.trace(np.dot(AB(a,b),rho))
    return ob
```

Comment: hmm.. after looking closer to the code, I am not sure why you needed the nested loop in the first place cause I don't see you utilize the loop?

Comment: oh sorry, my bad. I strongly believe it is because of the static value for `N_A` and `N_B` which are used  as the upper range limit in the loop inside Obs function.